# overflow-x container with variable width items

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get a vertical navigation list that will allow for elements that are wider than the nav itself. Users can enter whatever names they like for items that will appear here, so I have no control over their width, aside from maybe a very high max character length.

I've tried a few different methods, and seem to be coming up with multiple ways to achieve the same wrong result, once with flexbox once without. In both cases, if I have some "normal" sized elements that don't overflow outside of the nav, they look fine at first. But if I have an oversized element that overflows outside the container, and the user scrolls to the right, they will see the items boundaries don't extend to the right.

If I use the outer "item" for visual styling (light blue), they all end up the same width, but not wide enough to account for the overflow. If instead try styling the inner item (green), it is the correct width for only the overflowing item, and all the rest of the items are different widths based on their length.

Is there a way to:

1. Have all items appear to be the same width when there is a large item that overflows larger than the container
2. Without setting some arbitrary width, because I don't have control over how long the user strings might be
3. CSS only, no javascript

**Initial View, looks ok...**

[image: Initial View]

**Scroll to the right... looks bad!**

[image: Scrolled to the Right]

**Codepen**

Here's the [Codepen](http://codepen.io/jtheis85/pen/YPpzWL?editors=110)

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="item"><span>Item 1</span></div>
    <div class="item"><span>Item 2</span></div>
    <div class="item"><span>Item 3</span></div>
    <div class="item"><span>Item 4</span></div>
    <div class="item"><span>Super Long Item Name of Obliteration</span>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="flex-container">
  <span class="flex-item"><span>Item 1</span></span>
    <span class="flex-item"><span>Item 2</span></span>
    <span class="flex-item"><span>Item 3</span></span>
    <span class="flex-item"><span>Item 4</span></span>
    <span class="flex-item"><span>Super Long Item Name of Obliteration</span>
    </span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container {
  width:200px;
  height:400px;
  background-color: red;
  overflow:auto;
}

.item {
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background-color:lightblue;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

#flex-container {
  width:200px;
  height:400px;
  background-color: red;
  overflow:auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}

.flex-item {
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background-color:lightblue;
  white-space: nowrap;  
}

/* Content */
span > span,
div > span {
  background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: is this what you want (without using flexbox) http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OPbJWq

Comment: @EruPenkman No. The navigation I'm making is intended to be vertical. I also have a limited area in which to display it, but want items to be able to be larger than this area, such that the nav can be scrolled horizontally to see everything.

Comment: you don't' want the word to wrap to the next line ?

Comment: I've added a wrapping viewport div to my example ( I only worked on the second problem, haven't looked at the first menu yet) http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OPbJWq

Comment: @ZeRuBuES ideally I don't want it to word wrap to multiple lines.

Comment: @EruPenkman introducing a wrapping div seems to have made the difference for me. Write up an answer and I'll give you credit!

Answer (score 1):

Use overflow and text overflow

```css
.item,
.flex-item {
 overflow: hidden;
 text-overflow: ellipsis;
 max-width: 100%:;
}
```

[Codepen link](http://codepen.io/CodeHero/pen/XJNJpY)

Comment: An interesting approach. I might end up using the ellipsis idea for this problem or elsewhere. So you get a point for being useful, but I'm not accepting your answer because it doesn't address my specific question.